# Register, Deregister, perform all operations on eureka discovery from python web-services

Tags: python, netflix-eureka

I developed python web api to do some task which i need to register on spring eureka server for the discovery. Libraries are not available for it and available stuff of google is not helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka provides various restful API to perform this operation like registering, deregistering, heartbeat etc. 
[list of RESTful API which Eureka provides.](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Eureka-REST-operations)

following is the code by which you can register your service to eureka.
    import requests

```
url = "http://<eureka ip:port>/eureka/apps/PYTHON-API/"

payload = "{\n\"instance\": {\n\"instanceId\": \"10.90.21.55:5050\",\n\"hostName\": \"10.90.21.55\",\n\"app\": \"PYTHON-api\",\n\"ipAddr\": \"10.90.21.55\",\n\"status\": \"UP\",\n\"port\": {\"$\": \"5050\", \"@enabled\": \"true\"},\n\"securePort\": {\"$\": \"443\", \"@enabled\": \"true\"},\n\"statusPageUrl\": \"http://10.90.21.55:5050/status\",\n\"homePageUrl\": \"http://10.90.21.55:5050\",\n\"dataCenterInfo\": {\n\"@class\": \"com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo$DefaultDataCenterInfo\", \n\"name\": \"MyOwn\"\n}\n}\n}"
headers = {
    'content-type': "application/json",
    'cache-control': "no-cache"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```